# how to set git hook executable via gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, file-permissions, githooks

**TLDR**: how to add execute permissions / set executable via Gradle to a git hook script

I am developing an Android app with a team and was instructed to implement a company-wide pre-push script as a git hook.

I added a pre-push file with the script to the root directory of the project and added a copy script to copy it to the hooks folder.

I tried adding

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    copy {
        from "../pre-push"
        into "../.git/hooks"
    }
    tasks.create(name: 'gitExecutableHooks') << {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R +x .git/hooks/");
    }

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
}
```

the file is copied to the correct location but I get a warning

> .git/hooks/pre-push' hook was ignored because it's not set as
>   executable.

and naturally, the git hook doesn't execute.

(P.S. this works as intended on windows machines, and only fails on MacOS and Linux machines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the correct permissions.

```
copy {
    from "../pre-push"
    into "../.git/hooks"
    fileMode 0777
 }
```

This should do the trick for you.